# Why $5^{-\log_{3}\frac{10}{3}}=5^{\log_{3}\frac{10}{3}}$

Tags: logarithms

Why does $5^{-\log_{3}\frac{10}{3}}=5^{\log_{3}\frac{10}{3}}$. I think it's probably about the definition of logarithms but I'm not sure.

Comment: They're not equal as written:  one is more than $5$ and one is less than $5$

Comment: This is not true as written. You probably meant to write $5^{-\log_3 \frac{10}{3}} = 5^{\log_3 \frac{3}{10}}$, in which case it is true because $\log\frac{1}{x} = -\log x$

Comment: This is false. The equality isn't right.

Comment: @failedentertainment  you're right. it was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't.
\begin{align*}
5^{\log_3(10/3)} = 5.834{\dots}.  \\
5^{-\log_3(10/3)} = 0.17139{\dots}.
\end{align*}

Something that is true:  \begin{align*}
5^{-\log_3(10/3)} &= 5^{-(\log_3(10) - \log_3(3) )}  \\
    &= 5^{-\log_3(10) + \log_3(3) }  \\
    &= 5^{\log_3(3/10) }  \text{.}
\end{align*}